# Java Script Set min and max attribute for date

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I want to restrict date picking beyond 7 days from the current date.. help me out

```
<script> 
var date = new Date(); 
var startdate = date.getFullYear().toString()+"-"+ date.getMonth.toString()+"-"+date.getDate()+1.toString(); 
var maxdate =date.getFullYear().toString()+"-"+ date.getMonth.toString()+"-"+date.getDate()+6.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("min",startDate);
document.getElementById("demo").setAttribute("max",maxdate); 
</script>
```

Comment: Put the script inside a code block

Answer (score 0):

There are so many ways of doing this here's one:

```
var date = new Date();
var startDate = date.getFullYear() + "-" + date.getMonth() + "-" + date.getDate();
maxDate = startDate.split('-').map(Number);
maxDate[2] += 7;


demo.max = maxDate.join('-');
demo.min = startDate;
```